# How can I determine that $Y_n$ can be represented as a funtion of $X_n$

Tags: regression, matlab

On enter I'm having a sequence of pairs $(X_n, Y_n)$. Consider the following two graphics of two possible sequences.

[image]

[image]

in first case $Y_n$ can be modeled as $f(X_n)$ while in second case it obviously has no sense. The question is how can I determine if trying to represent $Y_n$ as $f(X_n)$ makes sense? Probable there is some criterium or something like that?

What can be done in multivariate situation (i.e. when we're trying to represent $Y_n$ as $f(X_1^{(n)}, X_2^{(n)}, ..., X_k^{(n)})$)?

Please note that trying to fit points with something graphicaly (e.g. like on first graph) and seeing if it fits the data is not OK. I'm looking for numerical criterium.

Either `R`/`Matlab` functions or link to pure mathematical article will be geat answer to my question!

**PS.** the variant that I'm thinking of is trying to look at variation of sequence. I.e. we order $(X_n, Y_n)$ in such a way that $X_{k-1} < X_k < X_{k+1}$ and then look at $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{|Y_i - Y_{i-1}|}{X_i - X_{i-1}}$. And there can even be an analog for multivariate case.

Comment: "Makes sense" in what sense? What is the criterion? In many cases you can fit *something* to your data that makes predictions better then random even though the model does not make much "sense" (e.g. it is hard to see any "sense" in kNN outputs).

Comment: On a broad sense, you can't without further information. How could you know the second one isn't some really short wavelength function association between Y and X?

Comment: @Firebug, hm! Yes it can be something like $sin(nx)$ -- have not thought of that. Maybe variation is really not bad criterium here, as it will throw out anything like $sin(nx)$

Comment: Your second one looks like a weak negative linear relationship to me but did you mean something else by f?

Comment: @mdewey the problem is that it's too week, my question is about finding "measure of wickness"

Comment: Then I recommend you mutual information. It doesn't answer your main question (i.e. is Y a function of X), but may help to elucidate the weakness of the relationship between X and Y somehow.